# Python 3 Requests: construct URI without calling GET method?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

So requests is a great library and often I used it like so:

```py
payload = {
    # ...
}
results = requests.get(some_url, params=payload)
```

and requests mangles all the key value pairs into the uri and goes ahead and makes the GET request.

Is there a way to construct the url of `results.url` without having to call `.get`?

Comment: try `furl` library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you will need to use the "raw" `Request` object and call its `prepare` method. Then you will be able to grab the prepared request's `url` attribute.

```
r = requests.Request('get', 'http://url', params={'a': 1, 'b': 2})
prepared_r = r.prepare()
print(prepared_r.url)
# http://url/?a=1&b=2
```

To make the request you will need a `Session` object:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.send(prepared_r)
```